# ¿Como utilizar async/await con funciones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

Tengo el siguiente problema y es que no acabo de entender *async/await* el problema es que necesito que la función *batch* se ejecute primero para realizar las otras funciones, y no quiero encadenarlos debido a que la función *batch* la utilizo en otras ocasiones, por eso inicialmente coloque un *setTimeout*, pero creo que utilizar *asyn/await* puede ser mejor.

¿Cómo podría realizar las funciones asyncronas?

```js
funcion batch();{
 $.ajax({
 url: `../../api/batch/${idBatch}`,
 type: 'GET'
 }).done((data, status, xhr) => {
     batch = data;
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 setTimeout(() => {
  if (proceso == 5) {
   busqueda_multi(batch);
   cargarTablaEnvase(batch);
   identificarDensidad(batch);
   calcularMuestras(batch);
  }
 }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
async function batch_ajax(){
  try{
     const result = $.ajax({
       url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`,
       type: 'GET'
     });
     return result;
  }catch(error){
     return null;
  }
}

$(document).ready(async function() {
  let batch = await batch_ajax();
  if (batch == null){
    document.write("La peticion fallo");
  }else{
    document.write(JSON.stringify(batch));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En el ready es realizar la consulta Ajax, este como tiene un `await` en la función `batch_ajax` espera hasta obtener una respuesta, una vez que se obtiene la respuesta, ejecuta los demás procesos, también es recomendable ponerlos dentro de un try/catch así puedes controlar si el servidor falla o no.